# PrimeFaces input field layout

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want this input mask or input field in PrimeFaces to be separated into 3 input field with the pattern of 1 digit in first and second input field and then 3 digit in the third. When saved will push the input 3 input field into single data string in a pattern of X.X.XXX where x is any digit string.

```html
<p:outputLabel value="Force Upgrade Version: " />
<p:inputMask id="value" value="#{systemConfigView.forceupgradeVersion.value}" styleClass="input-mid" mask="9.9.999" />

<p:outputLabel value="Force Upgrade Version: " />
<p:inputMask id="val1" value="#{}" styleClass="input-mid" mask="9" /> 

<p:inputMask id="val2" value="#{}" styleClass="input-mid" mask="9" />

<p:inputMask id="val3" value="#{}" styleClass="input-mid" mask="9" />
```

When saved this 3 input values will be pushed as one data string in a pattern X.X.XXX where X is digit string, and saved as 1 value which is `value="#{systemConfigView.forceupgradeVersion.value}"`

Comment: trying to combine the 3 values in each inputmask val1, val2, and val3 into one vaule which is the {systemConfigView.forceupgradeVersion.value}" in a format of X.X.XXX

Answer (score 1):

If i unterstood the scenario right you want to show the combined values of:

- val1 (X)
- val2 (X)
- val3 (XXX)

into one formatted string *systemConfigView.forceupgradeVersion.value* (X.X.XXX).

Maybe you should process val1,val2,val3 to your backing bean *systemConfigView.forceupgradeVersion* in three different fields and change *systemConfigView.forceupgradeVersion.value* accordingly.

Here is an example for possible events to process the values: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/inputmask?id=ajax-behavior-events

Only thing you will need is a method combining the three values to your string field. Thus *systemConfigView.forceupgradeVersion.value* will be a readonly field an should be displayed as an outputtext or label.